# Odoo 10 - Search condition

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to search based on the following condition:

```
.search([("product_id", "=", int(product_id)), ("language", "=", language), ['|', ("type", "=", "data"), ("type", "=", "translation")], ])
```

Which basically searchs in a given model (it is a custom one) for:

1. a given `product_id` AND
2. a given `language` AND
3. `type` column being either `"data"` OR `"translation"`

But I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.ion = distribute_not(normalize_domain(domain))\n  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/osv/ex
GATION:\nTypeError: unhashable type: \'list\'\n'>
```

Is the `search` condition properly defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have defined the search condition is incorrect.

Try this instead

`.search(['|', ("type", "=", "data"), ("type", "=", "translation"), ("product_id", "=", int(product_id)), ("language", "=", language)])`

Comment: Would not that `OR` everything?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#domains), ***"&"*** (default) and **"!"** are 2 arity, so you can do like this:

```
[("product_id", "=", int(product_id)),("language", "=", language),
'|', ("type", "=", "data"), ("type", "=", "translation")]
```